# How do I add classNames to the first element of the page without using a view?

Tags: ember.js

I want to add a wrapper class to the first div element in my page. I used to do this with a view. So, it seems that Ember 2.0 won't support Views anymore. So how can I do that now?

**view/application.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ['wrapper'],
});
```

**Resulting in the following page:**

```
<body class="ember-application">

<div id="ember573" class="ember-view wrapper">
    the rest of my page in this div
</div>

</body>
```

**How is this done now that views are deprecated?**

Comment: Could you post more code how your template looks??? Our outlets ( always first div ) <div class="container" id="contentContainer">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>

Answer (score 7):

I used css to solve this problem:

```
body > .ember-view {
  padding-left: 240px; //styles for container goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That will do the trick! However, I don't know if it's 100% reliable. I would love to know how to apply my own class to the wrapper.

Comment: Me too, but I didn't find a simple way to achieve this. I thought about using "embedding applications" (http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/) feature, but did not try, as css works for me and I find this method easier. If you wish, try to modify `index.html`, by adding there some div with desired class and use embedding.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a neat solution, but subclassing `Ember.Component` from inside `applications/view.js` works.

https://ember-twiddle.com/b15411266f996191605c

Comment: Looks like pretty useful hack.

Answer (score 3):

Like the others said, the only way to add a class using Ember 2.0 is to use a component on your page. The component has the same properties that the view had. Your page will have a component-only call in the template, like the following:

**your-page.hbs**

```
{{your-page-component}}
```

If you really don't want to have a component on your page, my advice to you would be to add manually a class name in your template:

**your-page.hbs**

```
<div class="your-page">
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Views` are deprecated in ember 2.0. The way to do things from now on is using `component` and `route`. You can specify which class name is applied to your component by doing:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
/* Wrap your component in primary class*/
  classNames: ['primary'],

/*defined class binding*/
  classNameBindings: ['isUrgent'],
  isUrgent: true
});
```

All information regarding on how to customize your `component` can be found in the ember documentation([click here to find out more](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/))

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to use `Views` now since they're deprecated. Use components instead, example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNameBindings: ['functionName'],

    functionName: Ember.computed(function() {
        // function logic
    })
});
```